# A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed in flutter web test

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

I get error when running widget test case in **flutter web**

A Timer is still pending even after the widget tree was disposed.
'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1485 pos 12: '!timersPending'

```
 testWidgets('OnBoardingPage renders correctly', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    tester.view.physicalSize = const Size(1000, 800);

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: OnBoardingPage(),
      ),
    );
    await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.menu));
    await tester.pump(); // Wait for animations and async tasks to complete.

    expect(find.byType(SideBar), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

---

EDITED
**Found the culprit:** Onboarding has this section which has duration of 10minutes how can I overlook this timer while testing

```
class CommunitySection extends StatelessWidget {
  const CommunitySection({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SectionHeader(heading: "Community"),
        _buildResponsiveCommunityWidget(context),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildResponsiveCommunityWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: const ScrollLoopAutoScroll(
        gap: 0,
        delayAfterScrollInput: Duration(seconds: 8),
        delay: Duration(seconds: 0),
        duration: Duration(minutes: 10),
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: _LogoWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible for anyone to tell you exactly what's wrong given the code you've shown. `OnBoardingPage` registers a `Timer` somewhere that never completes and is never cancelled.  If your test needs to wait some amount of time for that `Timer` to fire, then you should pass a `Duration` to `tester.pump`.

Comment: Thank you @jamesdlin, there is no timer in onBoardingPage, and setting duration to tester.pump gives me timeout error :(. And ha this is in **flutter web**

Comment: @jamesdlin I was wrong, you were correct, I have ScrollLoopAutoScroll widget with delay, duration how can I take care of this ? can you please tell me , thank you